# How to compare the value entered in the textbox with the value in the array(mysql dataset) sequentially with c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I converted a column of my mysql dataset into an array. I want to compare the strings entered in the textbox with each element in the array every time. My code is as follows. I entered the first string into the textbox. Then it turned true but then it showed false 13 times without letting me log into textbox.
*I converted from list to array because I got an error with list

```cs
List<string> cevaplar = new List<string>();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select cevap From soru_cevap", con.cn);

con.cn.Open();

MySqlDataReader oku = command.ExecuteReader();
while (oku.Read())
{
    string current = oku["cevap"].ToString();
    cevaplar.Add(current);
}
con.cn.Close();

string[] cevap = cevaplar.ToArray();


foreach (string a in cevaplar)
{
    
    if (textBox1.Text == a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("true");
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("false");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It show 13 falses means that your `List<string>` might contain 14 items, with one of them being the same string you input to the textbox.

It iterates all items inside the `List`. The result you got is expected.

Addition: you got a lot of unneeded code there.

Comment: but after it returns true, it does not allow me to enter a value in the textbox again. It only comes false 13 times from the message box

Comment: Maybe you did something after iterating the `List`. You should try to put some breakpoints to see what happened.

Comment: I think the value I entered in the textbox needs to be refreshed, but I couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: I deleted the value in the textbox by saying textbox1.Text = " " at the end of the if loop, but it worked the same way. Why not continue the foreach loop after the first couple. Do you have an idea?